# Update an activity after use of optionsMenu

Tags: android

I have an app with 5 activities. All these activities have settings that can be modified using the menu-button (optionsmenu) and selecting 'Settings'. This will open a dialog where all settings shown and where modification is possible.

When I close this settings-dialog by press the 'ok'-button, I want the activity that called optionsmenu to update its view.

The optionsmenu is activited like this in all activities:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.firstactivity_options_menu, menu);      
    return true;
}
```

And an example of onOptionsItemSelected follows...

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settings) {
        class.settingsDialog(this);         
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.about) {
        try {
            alertDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.settings_about), getAssets().open("about"), this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }   
    return true;
}
```

My problem is updating an activities view after I've had a match for R.id.settings. Is this possible? And if so, please give me some pointers...

Answer (score 0):

There's probably different ways to do this but after clicking `Ok` you can use an `Intent` to start the activity and call `finish()` on the activity to re-create the views

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a super/subclass approach or an interface since Dialogs do not force an Activity's `onResume()` method to be called.

Make a top abstract Activity class, e.g. `SuperMainActivity`.

```
public abstract class SuperMainActivity extends Activity
{
  public abstract void updateUI();
}
```

Then, have each of your Activities extend `SuperMainActivity` instead of just `Activity` and implement the `updateUI()` method.

Then in your `settingsDialog()` method, make it either:

Accept a `SuperMainActivity` param instead of an Activity/Context param.

or:

Do a cast when you want to callback, such as

```
((SuperMainActivity)myVariable).updateUI();
```

An interface is largely similar:

```
public interface ActivityCallback
{
  public void updateUI();
}
```

And each activity will **implement** ActivityCallback

such as

```
public class MainActivity implements ActivityCallback
{
  public void updateUI()
  {
    //implementation. Differs per class
  }
}
```

Then again, your `settingsDialog()` method should accept in an ActivityCallback parameter or you will cast again.

Note that if you do decide on this approach, when you call `settingsDialog()` you can still call it with

```
settingsDialog(this);
```

Since your Activities will meet the requirements for a parameter.